# "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Not Allowed)" - on email PHP script

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-email, email

I used the [Freelancer](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/freelancer/) template to create a one-page website being hosted on Github.

Everything works fine on the site, except the contact me php script that came with it. I've followed the instructions it gives to the letter, committed it, yet it shows an error every time someone tries to contact me (error reads "Sorry [NAME], it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!")

I tried it, and opened up the Developer Tools on Google Chrome. An error came up on the window, stating the error in the title, and pointing me towards the php script.

I've attached the PHP script below, and was wondering if someone could tell me what I was doing wrong.

Appreciate the help.

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])       ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
   }

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// Create the email and send the message
$to = '[MY EMAIL ADDRESS WENT HERE]'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@[MY USERNAME].github.io\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```